# Android camera stuck - can't catch the picture

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to use the CAMERA intent on adroid to take a picture and show it inside a picture view. The code below works fine until I take the picture. Then I can't confirm with "V" button and get back to my activity. If I click "X" button android goes back to my activity with no photo but If i click "V" to confirm the picture, nothing happens and i'm still stuck in the camera screen.

I'm using API 14 and testing on virtual and physical device with android 4.0.2.

Where is my mistake?

```
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HandScryActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private Uri uriSavedImage;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.handscry); 
        // Makes the filename
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
        uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
    }

    // Handles onGame clicked buttons
    public void btnHandClick(View v) {
            Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
        // according to clicked button
        switch (clickedButton.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnBackToGame:
                this.finish();
                break;
            case R.id.btnTakePicture:
                Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);               
                imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                break;              
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgHand);
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // Display image
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    img.setImageURI(uriSavedImage);                                
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go the solution, just in case someone else will stumble in my mistake. I got that sample from a website, but this part seems to stuck android and can't get "OnActivityResult" in case of success:

```
// Makes the filename
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
```

should be replaced with that

```
File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.jpg");        
uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by adding an `android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` generated using a `FileProvider` on version 4.4.4, when starting the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity.

The current activity is started like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Uri photoURI = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N
                    ? FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName(),photoFile)
                    : Uri.fromFile(photoFile);

// write the captured image to a file
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

// start it from the activity and not from the dialog so the request code will be the
// one expected and not the one from the dialog
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. I was able to open camera intent then capture the image but was unable to hit OK (tick) button on One Plus 6T. Debugging was of no help.
Then I figured out this issue is related to memory optimizations. I killed all other background apps and tried again and it worked.

for more info [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29267282/5582162). 
Option 2 worked for me in this link.

Copy pasting the answer from the link :

```
"When returning from the camera intent sometimes the app was being destroyed by the operating system (I'm assuming for memory
reasons). This resulted in sporadic behavior and my state object
would have several null fields upon returning, making my app crash.

Fix: Write state object to file before sending picture, load in my parent activity class which handles onCreate then goes to the subclassed activity."
```